What can we do to better support questions about other cryptocurrencies?
Apparently, there still is the sentiment that Bitcoin.SE is only for Bitcoin related questions. As the community has discussed a long time before, we would like to be a platform for questions about all cryptocurrencies.
There are already a few tags such as namecoin, ppcoin, zerocoin, dogecoin, litecoin, and ripple, which have accumulated some questions. There is also alternatives, which I feel is in dire need of an overhaul.
I think it is a problem if people perceive that Bitcoin.SE is not the place to ask their questions about other cryptos.

What can we do to better support other cryptocurrencies?
What can we do to change the perception that Bitcoin.SE is only for Bitcoin questions?


Sorry I'm a bit late to the party. Maybe add a straight altcoin tag? Is there a way to make a note at the top that bitcoin.SE is for all coins. I run an altcoin pool so if there can be some consensus on what should be changed, I'm willing to go through and change it. Maybe add tags for other altcoins? An announcement maybe? (I'm just giving out ideas here so if some of these are discussed already my apologies). What about making bitcoin.SE synonymous with a new cryptocurrency.SE or altcoin.SE?

The linked discussion in my first sentence actually shows that Bitcoin.SE started out as "Cryptocurrency.SE". We do have an [tag:altcoin] tag; it has 105 questions currently. It is also written in several areas of help, that questions about altcoins are on-topic, but it becomes more and more apparent that it is too subtle.

To be specific, the tags respective to altcoins we have are: litecoin, altcoin, auroracoin, blackcoin, namecoin, dogecoin, ppcoin, peercoin, mastercoin, quarkcoin, primecoin, maxcoin, datacoin, luckycoin, digitalcoin, trucoin, zerocoin, and vertcoin; ethereum, nxt, and ripple. I probably missed some.

Thanks for the info @Murch. Would ti be possible to add the tag freicoin ? I know it is a smaller alt, but it is established and has community backing. I do think that maybe broadening the SE by rebranding it as cryptocurrency.SE again might help (although I would bet there will be backlash). I'll go through over the next few days to try to find what I can answer of the altcoin tags as well as the mining tags. This question actually i feel might be valid again to discuss http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/302/being-strict-or-kind-about-newbie-questions?rq=1 (cont)

I think as time permits answering newbie questions might be good to get multiple perspectives. I do think that closing as a dupe after attempting to answer might be good. Also, I have in the past seen people replying to very old questions. Maybe a month of "overhauling" old questions to be relevant again would help out too?

@JoeWhite Just checked quickly, but it seems to me that we only have answers mentioning Freicoin. Since there are no question directly about Freicoin, there wouldn't be a tag. If someone asks a question about Freicoin, I will gladly add the tag to his question. The problem is though, that tags disappear after a while if there aren't more questions that use them. I think the minimum is two or three.
